# Enlightening Usage of C++11 decltype

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

I've just seen [this really nice talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DevDays/DevDays-2011-Netherlands/Devdays020) *Rock Hard: C++ Evolving* by Boris Jabes. In the section of the talk concerning *Higher-Order Generic Programming* he says that the following is an example of a function that is more generic with regards to its return type and leads to fewer template function overloads

```
template <typename Func>
auto deduce(const Func & f) -> decltype(f())
{..}
```

This however can be realized using plain template syntax as follows

```
template <typename Func>
Func deduce(const Func & f)
{..}
```

so I guess the example chosen doesn't *really* show the unique power of `decltype`. Can anyone give an example of such a more *enlightening* usage of `decltype`?

Comment: No. The first example means that ```deduce<Func>(f)``` returns the type of ```Func```'s result. The second example means that ```deduce<Func>(f)``` returns ```Func```. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Aah, sorry I missed the extra `()` inside the argument to `decltype`. My mistake.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your suspicions are incorrect.

```
void f() { }
```

Now `deduce(&f)` has type `void`, but with your rewrite, it has type `void(*)()`. In any case, everywhere you want to get the type of an expression or declaration, you use `decltype` (note the subtle difference in between these two. `decltype(x)` is not necessarily the same as `decltype((x))`).

For example, it's likely your Standard library implementation somewhere contains lines like

```
using size_t = decltype(sizeof(0));
using ptrdiff_t = decltype((int*)0 - (int*)0);
using nullptr_t = decltype(nullptr);
```

Finding out the correct return type of `add` has been a challenging problem throughout past C++. This is now an easy exercise.

```
template<typename A, typename B> 
auto add(A const& a, B const& b) -> decltype(a + b) { return a + b; }
```

Little known is that you can use `decltype` before `::` and in a pseudo destructor name

```
// has no effect
(0).~decltype(0)();

// it and ite will be iterators into an initializer list 
auto x = { 1, 2, 3 };
decltype(x)::iterator it = x.begin(), ite = x.end();
```

Comment: Could you please explain this a bit: `(0).~decltype(0)();`? I'm afraid I don't get it.

Comment: (0).~decltype(0)(); doesn't compile with gcc but does with clang. It is useful if 0 is replaced by a class object, it will be an explicit call the object's own destructor. So this is allowable (by clang at least) so that a template can work with class objects and also int 's etc. See https://godbolt.org/z/M4NNfN

Answer (score 1):

```
std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [](decltype (c.front()) val){val*=2;});
```

Autodeducting the value_type of the container *c* can't be done without *decltype*.

Comment: It can't be done only if you are using lambdas, given that they are not polymorphic (yet, let's hope they are in C++y). If you were using a polymorphic function object, it will be deduced automatically.

Answer (score 0):

One place that I use it, is where I need to make a variable that must have same type of another variable . but I'm not sure if in future the type will stay same or not .

```
void foo(int a)//maybe in future type of a changed
{
    decltype(a) b;
    //do something with b
}
```