# For the code below, I changed decltype(s1.size()) to int and the code worked just fine. Is decltype(s1.size()) redundant in this context?

Tags: c++, decltype

I'm new to C++. I'm trying to learn the concept of decltype. I saw this code online. I changed decltype(s1.size()) to int and the code worked just fine. Is decltype(s1.size()) redundant in this context or is there something I'm missing?

```
int main(){
    string s1 = "hello world";
    decltype(s1.size()) a = 0;
    while ( a < s1.size()){
        s1[a++] = 'x';
        cout << s1 << endl;
    }
}
```

Why decltype is needed here, int works the same?

Comment: It's hard to make out what you're asking here. Decltype is not "unnecessary and redundant." There are certainly times when it is useful, that's why they added it to the language. There are, however, other ways of specifying a type.

Comment: Your change to `int` can cause compilers to give a warning about the signed and unsigned comparison. That's one thing in this example that changes already. That said, `decltype`'s primary use is in generic code. For a user, it's typically an easier way to spell `std::string::size_type`.

Comment: Absent further clarification, I'm very tempted to close this question as a duplicate of either [What is decltype and how is it used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815221/what-is-decltype-and-how-is-it-used) or [Enlightening Usage of C++11 decltype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623496/enlightening-usage-of-c11-decltype). Perhaps one of those answers your question directly?

Comment: Lots of posts here regarding `decltype`. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[cpp]+decltype+is%3Aq.

Comment: I usually just do `auto a = 0u`.

Comment: It wouldn't work just fine if your string had more than `INT_MAX` characters in it.

Comment: Basically, in this case, it makes sure that `a` is the same type as `std::string::size_type`, as chris said.  While an `int` is fine for indexing most strings, it's not guaranteed to have a large enough range to properly index every `std::string`, hence making the index variable the proper type.  In this case, it's unnecessary, since `std::string::size_type` is `size_t` (or `std::size_t`; generally, an `unsigned int` on 32-bit systems, or an `unsigned int64_t` on 64-bit systems, but this may not necessarily be the case), which is a lot easier to both type and read.than `decltype(s1.size())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `decltype(s1.size())` redundant in this context?

I wouldn't use "redundant". To me, redundant means superfluous, i.e. specifying something that is already specified or need not be specified.

Perhaps you are thinking of "unnecessarily complicated".

Regardless, it is helpful to use `decltype` when you don't necessarily remember the return type of a function and you want to create more than one instances of the type. Also remember that you can use `auto` to deduce the type of an object from the expression used to initialize it.

You could use:

```
// Make the type of a to be deduced from the return type of s1.size()
auto a = s1.size();
```

and

```
// Define a type based on the return type of s1.size()
using size_type = decltype(s1.size());

// Use the type.
size_type a = s1.size();
size_type b = 0;
for ( ; b < a; ++b )
{
   ...
}
```

and

```
// Make the type of a to be deduced from the return type of s1.size()
auto a = s1.size();

// Make the type of b to be the same as the type of a.
decltype(a) b = 0;
for ( ; b < a; ++b )
{
   ...
}
```

More on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[cpp]+decltype+is%3Aq.

Comment: thank you so much for the helpful answer!! really thanksful!

Comment: @dzjustinli, you are welcome, Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Don't forget `std::string::size_type`, which is the name of the type that `string::size()` returns.